# Jdeps is not referring the env variables for execution

Tags: java, java-9, jdeps

I have multiple JDKs configured in my system i.e. JDK 8, 9 & 10 (early access). I need to execute the Jdeps tool available in JDK 9, however on issuing the `jdeps -version` command the one available in JDK 8 is getting executed.

I have the `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` environment variables set properly to JDK 9 path. When I issue `java -version` command it shows me the JDK 9 version, but surprisingly jdeps isn't behaving in that manner.

Can someone pls tell me how do I execute `jdeps` available in JDK 9?

Failed attempts so far:

1. `PATH` & `JAVA_HOME` set to JDK 9
2. Executed the command from `< JDK9 >/bin` directory

Completely removing JDK 8 for now, is not an option for me right now

[image: Screenshots FYR]

1. `pwd`: I'm currently in JDK 9's bin directory
2. `JAVA_HOME`: Points to JDK 9
3. `PATH`: I've intentionally skipped the JDK/bin directory here to prove the point that path doesn't point to any other JDK version
4. `java -version`: Hence proved that there's other java version being referred by *PATH*
5. Added `jdk(9)/bin` to `PATH`
6. `java -version`: We can see that JDK 9 is being used. Also the latest  value added to PATH is fine
7. `jdeps -version`: Here comes the trouble! It's JDK 8 used by jdeps

Comment: Is this macOS? Are you relying on the sym links in /usr/bin? Are you 200% sure that your PATH includes the JDK 9 bin directory before the JDK 8 bin directory?

Comment: If the (2) stated by you doesn't work, I wonder what else could one rely upon. OR (thinking more about what you might be doint wrong) you are not trying it this way `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jdeps -version`. Hope you're getting, that the reference could be incorrect there inspite of you being at any directory. Just be sure about it I would insist. To add to the question could you share sample screens of above as well?

Comment: @AlanBateman: No, this isn't on Mac OS. I'm trying this out on my CentOS VM

Comment: @nullpointer: Yes I've tried it the way you've mentioned. Adding screenshots on your request

Comment: What does `which jdeps` print? What does `alias jdeps` print?

Comment: @AlanBateman: I tried `which jdeps` and it gave me a weird location somewhere in `/usr/bin`, where jdeps was a symbolic link pointing somewhere else.  This might be a part of my VM setup, I'm not sure. 

Anyways, thank you very much for the useful pointer!

Comment: I'm digging this further to understand if this is indeed an issue with my VM setup. If I get sufficient evidence to prove this, I shall discard this post